# how is this evaluated for a function executed as callback?

Tags: javascript

When I execute myCallback through setTimeout. How is `this` evaluated inside myCallback ?

```
setTimeout(myCallback, 1000); 
// is 'this' inside myCallback going to be the same as
// if I invoked myCallback directly like this: myCallback() ?
```

Comment: Have you tried executing it? =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the "this" keyword work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0):

myCallback function will be invoked in a new scope, so "this" from the current object wont be available anymore and instead, "this" will refer to the global "window" object